# Django Rest Framewrok query problems with sum

Tags: python, django, forms, postgresql

Hi guys is anyone has same problem as me. The problem is on Django Rest Query, where I sum values from fields in database.

I got error:

1. Django Version: 1.7.7
2. Exception Type: TypeError
3. Exception Value:'Decimal' object is not iterable

## views

```
class invoiceList(APIView):

    @method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie)
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        user_pk = request.user.id
        org_id = request.user.organization.id
        total     = OutgoingInvoice.objects.filter(organization_id=user_pk, status_id__in=[2,3]).aggregate(total=Sum('total_invoice_amount', field="total_invoice_amount"))['total']

        serializer = OutgoingInvo(total, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

And my model is:

```
total_invoice_amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=5, max_digits=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Please post your stacktrace for more details on this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling the serializer with `total` which is a non-iterable type, namely a number.

From the docs:

> aggregate() is a terminal clause for a QuerySet that, when invoked, returns a dictionary of name-value pairs. The name is an identifier for the aggregate value; the value is the computed aggregate.

In your case:

```
OutgoingInvoice.objects.filter(organization_id=user_pk, status_id__in=[2,3]).aggregate(total=Sum('total_invoice_amount', field="total_invoice_amount"))
# >> {'total': 123.5} (example value)
```

I don't know what you want your serializer to show but if you are trying to have the sum of the amounts for each user you may do something like this:

```
User.objects.annotate(total=Sum("outgoing_invoice_set__total_invoice_amount")).filter(pk=user_pk, status_id__in=[2, 3])
```

Comment: Thax for answer, @qwattash